# Display fractions rather than decimals In Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I wrote the code below.

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols("x", real=True)
diff(x**(1/2), x)
```

---

Now Jupyter display output of the code.

[image]

- display exponent as decimals

  - not \sqrt{x} but x^(0.5)
- display fraction as decimals

  - not 1/2 but 0.5

---

Could you tell me the way to output as below  ?

[image]

- display exponent as sqrt

  - not x^(0.5) but \sqrt{x}
- display fraction as decimals

  - not 0.5 but 1/2